# Create points along a track at a specified straight line distance

Tags: arcgis-desktop, line, distance, arcgis-10.5

I'm using ArcMap 10.5. I have a track that I wish to place 30 points along at 400 meter intervals. The issue I am facing is that these points must be 400m apart measured in a straight line, not the actual distance along the track (see pic). I could do it manually but this would be quite time consuming. Is there a tool or extension that I can use in ArcMap to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: If create random points tool won't produce result, I post an old script for 10.2 or higher.

Comment: Is it a single feature or part of a network?

Comment: @Dan, it's part of a network but I could change it into a single feature if that would help.

Comment: @FelixIP I created a single polyline feature and tried the create random points tool but it does not space the points equally along the line at the required 400m.

Comment: How would you handle sections where the track might "bend back" on itself or sections where there are very tight turns. is the point just to have 30 points evenly spaced 400m (straight line) from the start of the track to the finish?

Comment: It would probably be faster to just do this manually since you only have 30 points.  create the first point, generate the buffer, create the second point, repeat.  Alternatively you could download one of the many tools on the ESRI code gallery to create points along the line at every meter or less.  Then, create an iterator in modelbuilder (or better-a Python tool) to select the first point, generate a near table, select the Euclidean distance with a value of 400 where the OBJECTID is greater that the current point, repeat.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Looks like doing it manually is the best option. I appreciate your feedback.